# Replace file upload (browse and submit) to just a button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Here's what the form looks like for testing purpose:

http://screencast.com/t/sp6WiM0H

The next step I want to take, is to remove the default browse/submit buttons for file uploads, and have everything done via a button (the blue "Add Pictures" button in the above link).

- User clicks on "Add Photo".
- User is able to browse a photo.
- When user has selected a photo, automatically 'submit' it.

How would you go about it?

I think JS might be required so I tagged it.

Thank you

Edit:

The form looks like:

```
<form action="upload_image.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="edit">
       <a href="" class="add blue_bg" onclick="performClick(document.getElementById('theFile'));">Add <br/> Pictures</a>
   </div>
   <input style="display:none;" type="file" id="theFile" name="photo" />
   <input type="hidden" name="owner_id" value="<?php echo $profileData[0]['id'] ?>">
</form>
```

It can browse, but the form is not being submitted it seems.

JS looks like:

```
function performClick(node) {
   var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
   evt.initEvent("click", true, false);
   node.dispatchEvent(evt);
}
```

Edit: got it now, I added this JS to handle form submit:

```
$("input[type='file']").on("change", function(){
    $("#photoForm").submit();
});
```

Also added `name="photo"` to the input type=file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use following code for the purpose.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function performClick(node) {
   var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
   evt.initEvent("click", true, false);
   node.dispatchEvent(evt);
}
</script>
<a href="#" onclick="performClick(document.getElementById('theFile'));">Open file dialog</a>
<input type="file" id="theFile" />
```

Note you can't just use .click() as some browsers does not support it.